# Can't resolve makeToast

Tags: java, android

**EDIT :**
*The entire issue was that since i miss-read .makeText for .makeToast, since 
i have corrected this i have found that both of the previous attempts actually work for my app. *

I'm having issues implementing Toast.makeToast method in my android app :

I tried

```
public void onRightCardExit(Object dataObject) {
Toast.makeToast(MainActivity.this, "Right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

as well as

```
public void onLeftCardExit(Object dataObject) {
Toast.makeToast(getApplicationContext(), "Left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

On the first one i get the issue

> "Can not resolve method 'makeToast.(android.Content.Context,
>   java.lang.String, int)' "

On the second one a similiar but just more specific pointer to my java file for the context

> "Can not resolve method
>   'makeToast.(com.sanruza.alpak.tinderlike.MainActivity,
>   java.lang.String, int)' "

I understand that the correct syntax is .makeToast( context, String, int ), but i still can't get it to work.

Comment: Check your imports

Comment: @cricket_007 already did and i have "import android.widget.Toast;"

Comment: Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Focus on "makeText" not "makeToast"

Comment: @MohamedFadhl He was hungy :P

Comment: @JAAAY looks like it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `makeText` instead of `makeToast`

```
Toast.makeText(context,toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

See the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) for more info..

Comment: Yap the third eddit made this the correct answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Please read the Google Developers link: [Developers Toast Document](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html)

This snapshot should clarify your concern:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

makeToast does not exist, you must use **makeText**.

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Msg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Msg", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```